# aws cli filter case sensitive

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I want to thank them for all the help you’ve given me.

Is there any way we can use the AWS cli to make it case sensitive?

I’m putting together a script to look up the name of the tag and the searches only work for me when it only matches the name of the tag.

Example

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=Web*" | jq -c '.Reservations[].Instances[] | ({IP: .PrivateIpAddress, Ambiente: (.Tags[]|select(.Key=="Environment")|.Value)})'
{"IP":"10.54.170.5","Ambiente":"PROD"}
{"IP":"10.54.165.11","Ambiente":"PROD"}
{"IP":"10.54.165.12","Ambiente":"PROD"}
{"IP":"10.54.166.11","Ambiente":"PROD"}
{"IP":"10.54.166.12","Ambiente":"PROD"}
{"IP":"10.54.167.11","Ambiente":"PROD"}
{"IP":"10.54.165.30","Ambiente":"PROD"}
{"IP":"10.54.167.30","Ambiente":"PROD"}
{"IP":"10.54.166.30","Ambiente":"PROD"}
{"IP":"10.54.165.13","Ambiente":"STAGE"}

➜  emanuel ~ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=web*" | jq -c '.Reservations[].Instances[] | ({IP: .PrivateIpAddress, Ambiente: (.Tags[]|select(.Key=="Environment")|.Value)})'
empty output
```

This is my script:

```
WILDCARD=$1
TAG=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values="$WILDCARD"*" --output text | grep TAG | grep "Name" | cut -f 3 | sort -u)
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for TAGS in $TAG ; do
echo -e "\x1B[01;31m Instancia: \x1B[0m" "$TAGS"
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values="$TAGS"" | jq -c '.Reservations[].Instances[] | ({IP: .PrivateIpAddress, Ambiente: (.Tags[]|select(.Key=="Environment")|.Value)})' | \
tr -d "{}"
```

How can I make the searches case sensitive ?

Regards,

Comment: Tags in Amazon EC2 are case-sensitive. This requirement is not coming from the AWS CLI. You will likely need to list _all_ instances, and then filter the list outside of the AWS CLI.